# Devise Mailer doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer

I have a problem. My Devise Mailer seems to work just fine in development. I get in my log that the confirmation messages are sent to respective mails when I try to signuup. But when I try to run the server in the production mode to see if the messages will actually be sent, I get this error:

```
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
```

But, when I add this line to my production.rb:

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

I can sign up, and I get in the log that the message is sent.

If anyone could elaborate, I would be most thankful.

Comment: what is your smtp setting inside the config/environments/production.rb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fix was to play around with the smtp settings. Thank you @nickcen